# wordpress contact form 7. Code searching

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

using the wordpress plugin, contact form 7, I created the form. Does anyone know where I can find a file with the code of this form? I mean, does this plugin store forms as a php code or in a database?

Comment: No we don't know, as you didn't show your code. Please [edit] the question to contain that code, this is called a [mcve]. You'll want to take the [tour] and read [ask] for a better experience on Stack Overflow. Oh, and btb: Welcome here!

Comment: Hello Adriaan, nice to meet you. I don't even now what code will be helpfull. I'm new in wordpress world. So my question is about structur this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just place the shortcode where ever you want like in page,post,custom post type anywhere the form to be appear, place something like this as shown in below.

[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]

id will be the form id you can escape the title as well.

Comment: I now how to use it, but i'm just thinking where forms are stored, in php files or database?

Comment: contact form 7 store their forms as custom post.

For more information you can visit official website of contact form 7
https://contactform7.com/faq/how-can-i-export-import-contact-form-data/

Comment: you can also refer to the another answer of SO. from where you can see the database table of your forms
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319945/want-to-restore-data-to-contact-form-7-wordpress

Comment: and if you want to design your form you don't need anything just put some html tags along with your form where you created from wp admin panel and use some css to provide some styling on it.

Comment: Thank you. You're second comment is that what i need.